# Is there docker image tagging without dependency in image ID

Tags: docker

I have docker environment with multiple tagging.

Like this:

```
image01:dev - > image01:staging - > image01:Prod
image02:dev - > image01:staging - > image01:Prod
```

In this case I have to remove one tagged environment, because they use same image ID. How can I change the image ID with tagging?

```
echo "Docker Compose Down"
docker-compose down
echo "Docker Compose Down ... Complete!"

echo "Docker Images Remove"
docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)
echo "Docker Images Remove ... Done!"
```

I get these errors:

> Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 3637565c5b84 (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container 67692aab8b26
>   Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 60892921e72f (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container 4be9a7ee6d0d
>   Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 8289f92814de (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container b06fb2e8b8a8
>   Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete b2c5303a61cb (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container 550f14f5d8d3
>   Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete db95989f3c68 (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container 3752ae226b9e
>   Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 6f2a973fcb00 (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container e0b92afc05c2

Comment: you are trying to delete an image that is being used by another container; If your tagged container uses that same image, it's logical not to let you delete it. Maybe you mean deleting the docker -> *docker rm* ?

Comment: Try not using `-f`, that is what is giving you the issue. The container layers are shared between your environments. If you do a force delete then this error is bound to come

Comment: its like this, i have docker registry that continuously store development container registry in there, then i will pull them to a machine and compose up

so when development ready to QC i just tag them with QC tag and compose up to  QC envirionment in the same host.

then when new development happen dev tagged container wont remove, the reason
same image hold both ruining container. i need a solution for that

Answer (score 0):

You need to see if you have some container in some state that is currently using these images before deleting it.

```
docker ps -a
```

You can see the containers that are not fully stopped and make `docker rm` with the container Id, then when you finish that process try to delete the images again.

Comment: its like this, i have docker registry that continously store development container registry in there, the i will host same machine with different port after tagging them.

so when development ready to QC i just tag them with QC tag and compose up QC envirionment.

Answer (score 0):

Independently of what containers are running, you can use the [`docker tag`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/) command to assign a tag to a different image.

```
docker tag image01:dev image01:staging
# Now "dev" and "staging" point at the same image
```

You then need to stop, delete, and restart containers to run them with the new image

```
docker stop staging
docker rm staging
docker run --name staging ... image01:staging
```

This will result in "dangling" images with no tags and no running containers.  You can clean these up

```
docker image prune -f
```

Note that in many clustered environments the literal name of a tag is an important identifier, and you shouldn't reuse tag names like this.  In Kubernetes, for example, it's very easy to trigger a zero-downtime rolling upgrade of a Deployment object, but only if you're changing some textual aspect of the deployment configuration; making it restart a Deployment with a newer version of the same image tag is significantly harder.  I'd suggest using a tag name like a source control commit ID or a date stamp and just directly running that

```
docker run --name staging ... image01:20190610
```

[`docker image prune -a`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/) will clean up images with tags but no running containers, on the assumption that they can always be rebuilt or pulled again from a repository.